# Is it safe to install TensorFlow on Windows

Tags: windows, machine-learning, tensorflow

Thank you for your interest in this topic.

To put things into their context, I am a newbie to TensorFlow (and to the whole concept as well), I haven't started working with it yet and I wanted to start with tutorials and try things by myself.
My question is: is it possible (and safe) to install TensorFlow on Windows (I use Windows 8.1)?

Actually I have visited many forums and blogs and the answers seemed contradictory and as someone who's going to start from 0, it all sounded more and more confusing with the more I read. Some persons said it can be installed but is not stable and recommended yet (however I didn't find anything about the windows installation in the official TensorFlow documentation). Other persons said it was possible to install on windows Docker (something I have heard about for the first time and still can't get it) but I found many comments saying that installing it on Docker too brought up many unnecessary issues and was a waste of time (note that I am learning this for my internship and I can't waste a lot of time on something that I may know won't work in the end, because I have an output to give by the end of my internship period). All this made me decide to work on Ubuntu (installed on VMWare Workstation) but I'm not sure if using a virtual machine is recommended and it seems like my boss didn't like the idea of using Ubuntu (from what I've understood, they are used to work with Windows, as I am).
Answering this topic can help me a lot on my choice so thank you again for your interest. Looking forward to your answers. Thank you.

Comment: TensorFlow officially can be installed for Windows on Docker only. And yes, it gives some performance overhead so better to avoid docker. From my experience the best option is to go for dual boot set up - install Ubuntu in addition to the Windows without VMWare (since VMWare itself could add some performance overhead and possible issues)

Comment: Looks like it will be possible to use Tensorflow on Windows 10 once the Anniversary edition comes out (using the built in bash shell and Ubuntu libraries). If you have access to the Insiders Preview of Windows 10, you can try it today, but it's still a beta product - see this post for more information. http://www.hanselman.com/blog/PlayingWithTensorFlowOnWindows.aspx

Comment: @MaximHaytovich thank you for your quick answer! I thought of that as a solution too but I think I will need more than just one machine for my work, that's why I opted for the Ubuntu on VMWare. So if I have to only choose between Windows and Ubuntu on VMW, do you recommend Ubuntu?

Comment: @AvishkarBhoopchand thank you for your quick answer as well! Actually I've heard Windows 10 is still not stable and everyone I know that has installed it regretted it later (especially persons who are not using it for fun but for work and development purposes). I will definitely check the link. Thank you

Comment: @TaoRinVVHL well, if you need several machines running simultaneously than I'd suggest to go for docker (if you don't need anything from ubuntu except tensorflow). Technically docker is some kind of a VM also, but it is a bit lighter and saves you trouble installing and configuring ubuntu etc.

Comment: @MaximHaytovich actually my Ubuntu machine is already installed and configured, I also have installed python 3.5. thank you.